# Count cases by dates and save it in a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

In one data frame (called X) I have `Patient_admitted_id`, `Date`, `Hospital_ID` of tested covid positive patients (I show this data frame below). I want to generate a separated data frame (called Y) with `Dates` of the calendar, total number of covid `Cases` and `cumulative` cases.

I dont know how to generate the column `Cases`

X data frame:

```
data = {'Patient_admitted_id': [214321,224323,3234234,23423],
        'Date':  ['2021-01-22', '2021-01-22','2021-01-22','2021-01-20'], # This is just an example I have created here, the real X data frame contains proper date values generated with Datatime
        'Hospital_ID': ['1', '2','3','2'],
        }
X = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Patient_admitted_id','Date', 'Hospital_ID' ])
X
    Patient_admitted_id     Date    Hospital_ID
0   214321               2021-01-22     1
1   224323               2021-01-22     2
2   3234234              2021-01-22     3
3   23423                2021-01-20     2
...
```

Desirable Y data frame:

```
    Date        Cases    Cumulative
0   2021-01-20    1         1           
1   2021-01-21    0         1         
2   2021-01-22    3         4     
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) by days with counts by [`Resampler.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.size.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for cumulative counts:

```
X['Date']= pd.to_datetime(X['Date'])
                          
df = X.resample('D', on='Date').size().reset_index(name='Cases')       
df['Cumulative'] = df['Cases'].cumsum()      
print (df)
        Date  Cases  Cumulative
0 2021-01-20      1           1
1 2021-01-21      0           1
2 2021-01-22      3           4
```

Comment: One-liner: `X.astype({"Date": np.datetime64}).resample('D', on='Date').size().reset_index(name="Cases").assign(Cumulative=lambda x: x["Cases"].cumsum())`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` on Date column and call `size` to get the count of individual Dates, you can then simply call `Cumsum` on cases to get the desired output

```py
out = X.groupby('Date').size().to_frame('Cases').reset_index()
out['Cumulative'] = out['Cases'].cumsum()
```

`out` variable holds the desired dataframe.

**OUTPUT**:

```py
         Date  Cases  Cumulative
0  2021-01-20      1           1
1  2021-01-22      3           4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a solution with [pd.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

```
X['Date']= pd.to_datetime(X['Date'])
df = X.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='D')).size().reset_index(name='Cases')       
df['Cumulative'] = df.Cases.cumsum()    
df
```

**Output**

```
    Date        Cases   Cumulative
0   2021-01-20  1       1
1   2021-01-21  0       1
2   2021-01-22  3       4
```